# Windows Crypto API AES decryption leaves first block partially decrypted

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, aes, cryptoapi

I'm coding c++ FYI

Ok so I have the windows Crypto API generating an RSA key pair so that I may properly export my generated AES key.

All works well, my code decrypts **ALL** of the data **WITH THE EXCEPTION** of 10 bytes starting at offset 0x2 in the outputted plaintext

It seems that offset 0x2 is random, while 0x3 is what it should be, while 0x4-0xC is 0xB8 consistently.

--Message Generation

```
char message[700];
memset(message, 't', sizeof(message));
```

--Encryption

```
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, eof, 0, (LPBYTE)tmp_blk_buff, &p_block_size, TMP_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE(context->in_size))
```

--Decryption

```
CryptDecrypt(context->aes_hKey, NULL, eof, 0, (LPBYTE)tmp_blk_buff, &p_block_size)
```

There is to much code to past in here.

Am I missing a dwFlag or something...I'm pretty stumped on this.
Thanks for any input.

[image: The Plain Text]

Comment: [Encrypt example.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [Decrypt example.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry but that example does not apply to this situation but thanks